# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

hi guys i don't know why when i click on "register" i have this exception:"`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.NullPointerException`".

```
 at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:247)
 at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.RegisterActivity.access$800(RegisterActivity.java:37)
 at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:114)
```

Now i show you my code:

ps: I hope that you can help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

REGISTER ACTIVITY:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputFullCognome;

    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private EditText inputEmail2;
    private EditText inputNumeroAppartamento;
    private EditText inputNomeEdificio;
    private EditText inputZonaMetropolitana;



    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputFullCognome=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.cognome);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero_telefonico);
        inputEmail2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email2);
        inputNumeroAppartamento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero_appartamento);
        inputNomeEdificio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome_edificio);
        inputZonaMetropolitana = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zona_metropolitana);



        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
//                    MainActivity.class);
                    DopoLogin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String cognome = inputFullCognome.getText().toString().trim();

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String email2 = inputEmail2.getText().toString().trim();
                String numero_appartamento = inputNumeroAppartamento.getText().toString().trim();
                String nome_edificio = inputNomeEdificio.getText().toString().trim();
                String zona_metropolitana = inputZonaMetropolitana.getText().toString().trim();

           boolean ok=false;
              //  ok=isValidEmailAddress(email2);


                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()&& !cognome.isEmpty()&& !email2.isEmpty()&& !numero_appartamento.isEmpty()&& !nome_edificio.isEmpty()&& !zona_metropolitana.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name,cognome, email, password,email2,numero_appartamento,nome_edificio,zona_metropolitana);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter all your details or check your email if it is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
   public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email2) {
        String emailRegEx;
        Pattern pattern;
        // Regex for a valid email address
        emailRegEx = "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+\\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
        // Compare the regex with the email address
        pattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegEx);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email2);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name,final String cognome, final String email,
                              final String password,final String email2,final String numero_appartamento,final String nome_edificio,final String zona_metropolitana) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String cognome = user.getString("cognome");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String email2 = user.getString("email2");
                        String numero_appartamento = user.getString("numero_appartamento");
                        String nome_edificio = user.getString("nome_edificio");
                        String zona_metropolitana = user.getString("zona_metropolitana");



                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name,cognome, email,email2,numero_appartamento,nome_edificio,zona_metropolitana, uid, created_at);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("cognome", cognome);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("email2", email2);
                params.put("numero_appartamento", numero_appartamento);
                params.put("nome_edificio", nome_edificio);
                params.put("zona_metropolitana", zona_metropolitana);




                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

XML ACTIVITY REGISTER:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_register"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cognome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_cognome"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero_telefonico"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_numero_telefonico"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email2"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero_appartamento"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_appartment_number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nome_edificio"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_building_name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/zona_metropolitana"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_area"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/città"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_city"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="#ea4c88"
            android:text="@string/btn_register"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToLoginScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

APP CONTROLLER:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private com.android.volley.RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public com.android.volley.RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

    private class RequestQueue {
        public <T> void add(Request<T> req) {
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: post your xml, check! if you have included the same button id in the xml also

Comment: i posted XML...help me please

Comment: hey @Markus you logcat shows error at line 247 in register activity, i cannot count the lines please tell from which line number your posted code start from as you have missed the import lines

Comment: this is line 247:         AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);